# Emulator doesnt load anymore, what can i do?

Tags: flutter, emulation, pubspec

In VSCode Flutter Emulator doesnt load.

Error: No pubspec.yaml file found.
This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project.

Flutter run doesnt work.

Comment: please check if you are in the root of project where you can hit the command ls -la (in cmd or terminal ) which will show you the list of files and folders in the project.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are in the root of your project.
if not - right click on your main.dart file and run that file on terminal.
then flutter clean & pub get & run worked for me .

Comment: When i enter flutter clean there is the same output => 


Error: No pubspec.yaml file found. This command should be run from the root of your Flutter project. I always clicked in main.dart..but nothing changed.